# Safari iOS autofill "country" not working

Tags: javascript, ios, autocomplete, safari, autofill

I am currently dealing with some issues with the "autofill" feature for Safari iOS. In this particular example, "autofill" works fine for all fields except "country", which happens to be a custom dropdown. 
Weird thing is, "state", which is the same type of custom dropdown, works.
I am also displaying the "native" "select" that sits behind the custom one, for better debugging.
Additionally, at the end of the form, I am including a fully native Country "select", autofill works there. 
Any idea why the first/custom Dropdown won't work? Again, please consider that "state" is also a custom dropdown and works.

```html
<select name="country" autocomplete="country"><option value="">

 Country2

</option> <option value="TUV">Tuvalu</option>
 <option value="UGA">Uganda</option>
 <option value="UKR">Ukraine</option>
 <option value="ARE">United Arab Emirates</option>
 <option value="GBR">United Kingdom</option>
 <option value="USA">United States</option>
 <option value="UMI">United States Minor Outlying Islands</option>
 <option value="URY">Uruguay</option>
 <option value="UZB">Uzbekistan</option>
 <option value="VUT">Vanuatu</option>
 <option value="VEN">Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of</option>
 <option value="VNM">Viet Nam</option>
 <option value="VGB">Virgin Islands, British</option>
 <option value="VIR">Virgin Islands, U.S.</option>
 <option value="WLF">Wallis and Futuna</option>
 <option value="ESH">Western Sahara</option>
 <option value="YEM">Yemen</option>
 <option value="ZMB">Zambia</option>
 <option value="ZWE">Zimbabwe</option>
</select>
```

Example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BqJMWq

[image]

Comment: same issue here, on a <SELECT> with css property `display:hidden` - any news?

Comment: @axel negative. seems to be some sort of erratic random bug. i've seen it in a lot of different forms/websites (certain select fields, sometimes the country, sometimes the state... not getting properly auto populated)

Comment: Indeed I saw some examples where this works perfectly.. and some other where it does not at all... but no clue about the reason. i keep investigating.

Comment: I notice that [Mozilla says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete#Values) `autocomplete="country"` is for the **country code**. The [HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#attr-fe-autocomplete-country) confirms, that designates the 2-letter ISO-3166 code. There's a different setting for `"country-name"`.